# How do I find out what I can do with event object return by event listener?

Tags: reactjs

I've saw some code use `event.target.reset()` onSubmit handler. **How do I find out what I can do with event object return by event listener?** I know it use to reset search field.

I've Search through react doc on synthetic event there isnt much information regarding what event object is, what I can do with it and how to use them. Before I saw `event.target.reset()` to reset form. I use setState to clear the search form, which is dumb.

`event.target.reset()`

Comment: why do you think clearing state object to clear a form is dumb?

Comment: It will cause a rerender of component since I use setState. Isn't that very unnecessary?

Comment: you've binded formInputs with state object, but you want to clear the formInput's without clearing the state? is this what you're looking for? and obviously when you change the state the component will re-render. And what makes you to be ok with state object holding values of formInputs when formInput's are cleared?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mix [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) and [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) approaches. If you have something like `<input value={this.state.value}/>` then you shouldn't use `event.target.reset()`. You'll get a warning or an error.

You can check the documentation to get a list of [existing events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events), the base [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) and [HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)

In most cases you just assume that your event handler is only bound to a specific elememnt type and call its methods through `event.target.`